# How can I use a label in iOS to make editable text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, label, calculator

I want to make a calculator that when I input values it prints into a label?

I already have the input values coding sorted out. Now I just need to figure out how to print and integer/string onto a label

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
//in viewDidLoad    
[self.yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelUsingContentsOfTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    -(void)updateLabelUsingContentsOfTextField{
       self.yourLabel.text = self.yourTextField.text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an UITextField and change its appearance to seem like an UILabel.

Comment: So how would i code it so it would be like
<textintheUITextField> = <textIWantToHaveInTheUITextField>

Comment: You can do it without coding, changing its properties in IB. To set the text you could use the setText method of the UITextField: [mytextfield setText:@"Something"];

Comment: If it works, do you think you could perhaps upvote the answer from @CarlosSolanaMartínez? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial takes you step by step through creating a calculator in XCode. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBTXtwTRdk0

Answer (score -1):

try this solution

```
-(void) updateLabelText: ( NSString *)txt
{
   [self.myLabel performSelectorOnMainThread : @ selector(setText : ) withObject:txt waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```